# Can someone translate these for me? Thanks

Tags: translation

Translate these for me? Thanks. naui hoejeon-eun naui yeong-eolo mal-eul meomchunda

Comment: Please type this in Korean and let us know if you have tried translating it yourself, and if yes what problem you had, and any other detail you have about this sentence (where is it from, more context, etc). In it's current state it is highly likely this question will get closed or deleted.

Comment: This sounds like gibberish. The best I can make out is something like "My rotation is with my English stops talking".

Comment: Hi John - sorry, but it seems like we can't make this out! If you have a Hangul transcription, a picture, or some audio of the original, perhaps you could add it and we can try again.

Comment: It seems the original sentence was "나의 회전은 나의 영어로 말을 멈춘다". The translation will be "My rotation stops talking with my English" then.